# Hidden image with javascript in textbox when is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change the visibility of an image inside a textbox.
When i select the textbox "search", the placeholder become invisible.
you can do the same thing with a picture inside it?

The code:

```
<div id="ricerca">
                  <form >
                  <input type="text" class="ricerca" value="Search" onblur="if (this.value == '') this.value ='Search';" onclick="if (this.value == 'Search') this.value ='';"  >
                  <input type="submit"  id="lente" class="lente"  value="show" style="border:none;">
                  </form> 
</div>
```

this is the link: http://www.lookcommunication.it/korus/WEPA/IT/

Comment: Yes you can.. What have you tried?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with javascript, but i try with some IF and giving a ID to the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some Jquery Function for you

```
$(".ricerca").click(function() {
  $("#lente").hide();
 });
$(".ricerca").focusout(function() {
  $("#lente").show();
  $("#lente").css('marginTop',"-22px");
 });
```

Have a look here [JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rpqvX/8/)

Comment: Yea there are many ways to do ..For instance previously i used css block none...but i tought jquery hide show wud be very much easy ..

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you>

```
<style type="text/css">
input.image-placeholder{
    background-image:url("image path");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: center left;
}
</style>

<div id="ricerca">
              <form >
              <input type="text" class="ricerca" value="Search" onblur="if (this.value == '') this.className= this.className + ' image-placeholder';" onclick="if (this.value == 'Search') this.className='ricerca';"  >
              <input type="submit"  id="lente" class="lente"  value="show" style="border:none;">
              </form> 
</div>
```